# How to fix 'Server sending data faster than client can handle, server freezes'

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm using a java server to facilitate online multiplayer in my game made with GameMaker Studio, the players will send data to the java server which will process the data and send it to the players. The problem is that when a player with a slow internet connection is not being able to handle the amount of data being send to it, it will cause the server to freeze for all players (the server will no longer process any data send by other players).

I have simulated slow internet speeds by using NetLimiter and setting the download speed of one laptop at 5 kb/s, while maintaining proper speed at other laptops. I have tried to send ACK packets from the java server to the client and if it doesn't respond in 1 second no more data will be send to that client (and eventually the client will be kicked). This has reduced the chance of freezing the server, but it will still happen occasionally.

Main.java

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

public class Main
{
    static ServerSocket serverSocket_;
    static HashMap<String, ServerInformation> servers_;
    static int verboseLevel_;
    static int threadTimeout_;
    static int masterPort_;
    static int serverNumber_;
    static int socketTimeOut_;

    static {
        Main.serverSocket_ = null;
        Main.servers_ = new HashMap<String, ServerInformation>();
        Main.verboseLevel_ = 5;
        Main.threadTimeout_ = 10;
        Main.masterPort_ = 6510;
        Main.serverNumber_ = 1;
        Main.socketTimeOut_ = 6000;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            setupServerAndCleanup(Main.masterPort_);
            while (true) {
                handleIncomingConnection();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void setupServerAndCleanup(final int port) throws IOException {
        (Main.serverSocket_ = new ServerSocket()).setReuseAddress(true);
        Main.serverSocket_.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Main.masterPort_));
        System.out.println("Server socket up and running on port " + Main.masterPort_);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Main.serverSocket_ != null) {
                    try {
                        Main.serverSocket_.close();
                        System.out.println("Server socket closed, port released");
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    static void handleIncomingConnection() throws IOException {
        final Socket clientSocket = Main.serverSocket_.accept();
        clientSocket.setSoTimeout(Main.socketTimeOut_);
        final ClientThread client = new ClientThread(clientSocket);
        client.start();
    }

}
```

ClientThread.java

Case 1 is the part dealing with sending data to the clients, in particular this line:

```
thread2.out_.print(msg);
```

If more data is being send than one client can handle the server will freeze for all other clients as well.

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

    public class ClientThread extends Thread
    {
    Socket clientSocket_;
    String clientIp_;
    String serverIp_;
    ServerInformation server_;
    PrintWriter out_;
    BufferedReader in_;
    boolean prepareTermination_;
    boolean terminated_;
    private static final Pattern numberPattern;

    static {
        numberPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    }

    public ClientThread(final Socket sock) {
        this.clientSocket_ = sock;
        this.clientIp_ = this.clientSocket_.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
        this.serverIp_ = null;
        this.server_ = null;
        this.prepareTermination_ = false;
        this.terminated_ = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            this.out_ = new PrintWriter(this.clientSocket_.getOutputStream(), true);
            this.in_ = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket_.getInputStream()));

            long lastActionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while (true) {

                if (this.in_.ready() || System.currentTimeMillis() - lastActionTime >= 1000 * Main.threadTimeout_) {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastActionTime >= 1000 * Main.threadTimeout_) {
                        //this.logDebugMessage(3, "Thread was killed due to prolonged inactivity (" + Main.threadTimeout_ + " seconds)");
                        this.terminateThread();
                        return;
                    }

                    final String tempInputLine;
                    if(((tempInputLine = this.in_.readLine()) == null )){
                        this.terminateThread(); //end thread                        
                        return;             
                    }
                    else
                    {                   
                        lastActionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();                    
                        final String inputLine = tempInputLine.trim();
                        if (ClientThread.numberPattern.matcher(inputLine).matches()){
                        final int val = Integer.parseInt(inputLine);
                        switch (val) {
                          case 1: { //send data to other players
                                final int parseCount = Integer.parseInt(this.in_.readLine().trim());
                                final StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                                for (int j = 0; j < parseCount; ++j) {
                                    msg.append(String.valueOf(this.in_.readLine().trim()) + "|");
                                }
                                for (final ClientThread thread2 : this.server_.ipToClientThread_.values()) {
                                    if (thread2 != this) {
                                        thread2.out_.print(msg);
                                        thread2.out_.flush();
                                    }
                                }
                                //this.logDebugMessage(5, "Packet for others: '" + msg.toString() + "'");
                                break;
                            }   

                            case 2: { //remove game server
                                //this.logDebugMessage(1, "A game server has been deleted, ip: " + ipServer);
                                Main.servers_.remove(this.server_.ip_);
                                this.serverIp_ = null;
                                for (final ClientThread thread : this.server_.ipToClientThread_.values()) {
                                    thread.prepareTermination_ = true;
                                }
                                this.terminateThread();
                                return;
                            }
                            case 3: { //connect new client
                                final String ipServer = this.in_.readLine().trim();
                                final String ipClient = this.in_.readLine().trim(); 
                                this.logDebugMessage(1, "A client wishes to connect to a server, client: " + ipClient + ", server: " + ipServer);
                                final ServerInformation info = Main.servers_.getOrDefault(ipServer, null);
                                if (info == null) {
                                    System.out.println("Connection to the server failed, no such server in the server list");
                                   this.out_.print("*" + 1 + "|" + 1 + "~" + "|");
                                   this.out_.flush();                                   
                                break;
                                }
                                this.server_ = info;
                                this.server_.ipToClientThread_.put(ipClient, this);
                                this.logDebugMessage(1, "Connection success");
                                this.logDebugMessage(5,"Map: " + this.server_.ipToClientThread_);
                                    this.out_.print("*" + 1 + "|" + 2 + "~" + "|");
                                    this.out_.flush();
                                break;
                            }         
                            case 4: { //disconnect client
                                final String ipClient = this.in_.readLine().trim();
                                this.server_.ipToClientThread_.remove(ipClient);
                                this.logDebugMessage(1, String.valueOf(ipClient) + " disconnected from the server at " + this.server_.ip_);
                                this.serverIp_ = null;
                                this.terminateThread();
                                return;
                            }                   

                            case 5: { //host create new game
                                if (Main.serverNumber_ > 1000000) {
                                Main.serverNumber_ = 10;    
                                }
                                Main.serverNumber_ += 1;                                
                                final String ipServer = Integer.toString(Main.serverNumber_); //unique server number
                                final String ipHost =  this.in_.readLine().trim(); //host 
                                final String name = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //Server name
                                final String description = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //class
                                final String servervar1 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //max players
                                final String servervar3 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //current lap
                                final String servervar4 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //total laps
                                final String servervar5 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //status
                                final String servervar6 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //Password
                                final String servervar7 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //Online version
                                final String servervar8 = this.in_.readLine().trim(); //Game server
                                final long servervar9 = System.currentTimeMillis(); //server creation time
                                //this.logDebugMessage(1, "A game server has been registered, ip: " + ipServer + ", name: " + name + ", description: " + description + ", servervar1: " + servervar1);
                                final ServerInformation gameServer = new ServerInformation(name, servervar1, servervar3, servervar4, servervar5, servervar6, servervar7, servervar8, servervar9, ipHost, ipServer, this.clientSocket_, this.out_, this.in_);
                                gameServer.description_ = description;
                                gameServer.ipToClientThread_.put(ipHost, this);
                                this.server_ = gameServer;
                                Main.servers_.put(ipServer, gameServer);
                                this.serverIp_ = ipServer;
                                break;
                            }                               
                            default: {
                                this.logDebugMessage(0, "Unrecognized case: '" + inputLine + "', " + val);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (inputLine.length() > 0) {
                        this.logDebugMessage(0, "Unformated '" + inputLine + "'");
                        if (this.server_ != null) {
                            this.server_.out_.print(inputLine);
                            this.server_.out_.flush();
                        }
                    }
                    if (this.prepareTermination_) {
                        this.terminateThread();
                        return;
                    }
                    continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                this.terminateThread();
            }
            catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
            try {
                this.terminateThread();
            }
            catch (IOException e4) {
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //debug messages
    void logDebugMessage(final int requiredVerbose, final String msg) {
        if (Main.verboseLevel_ >= requiredVerbose) {
            System.out.println("[" + this.clientIp_ + "]  " + msg);
        }
    }

    //terminate thread
    void terminateThread() throws IOException {
        if (!this.terminated_) {
            if (this.serverIp_ != null) {
                Main.servers_.remove(this.serverIp_);
            }
            this.clientSocket_.close();
            this.in_.close();
            this.out_.close();
            this.logDebugMessage(3, "Cleanup successful");
            this.terminated_ = true;
        }
    }
}
```

How to avoid the server from freezing if more data is being send to a client than it can handle, so that the server can continue sending data to the other clients?

**Edit**
So I have tried using `ExecutorService`, but I must be doing something completely wrong because no data is being send by the java server.

```
for (final ClientThread thread2 : this.server_.ipToClientThread_.values()) {
    if (thread2 != this) {
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                thread2.out_.print(msg);
                thread2.out_.flush();
            }
        });

        executorService.shutdown();     
    }
}
```

It would be great if you could show me how to implement `ExecutorService` the right way.

Answer (score 1):

If a delay in the client processing doesn't matter, this part should be done in a distinct flow execution for each client :

```
for (final ClientThread thread2 : this.server_.ipToClientThread_.values()) { 
        thread2.out_.print(msg);
        thread2.out_.flush();            
}
```

For example :

```
for (final ClientThread thread2 : this.server_.ipToClientThread_.values()) { 
      if (thread2 != this) {
            new Thread(()-> {   
                                thread2.out_.print(msg);
                                thread2.out_.flush();
                            })
                      .start(); 
        }
}
```

Note that creating Threads has a cost. Using `ExecutorService` could be a better idea.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the above code but it didn't solve the server freezing problem. I will try the 'ExecutorService' hopefully this will be the solution.

Comment: I have tried adding ExecutorService but I must be doing something wrong: see the edit of my question. If you could show me how to implement it the right way it would be really helpful.

Comment: `ExecutorService` is not "the" solution. It "just" makes lower level things handled by this API. I think that to solve the issue you should add some specific traces to indicate where exactly it freezes.